# node.js mongodb connection latency for large data

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoimport

I am doing mongoimport with csv type through my node.js app. At localhost, the results are really good. 
When I moved my nodejs codebase and mongodb to server env (both in the same server), the results are not so pleasing as below. 
Is this an issue with network latency that cannot be addressed or am I missing something?

```
Config:
RAM-8GB; csvdata-75000 rows = 9.12MB; Server-Windows server 2008; 
mongodb connection accepted time:- 
browser client localhost - 75000 rows - instantaneous 
browser client remote - 15 rows - instantaneous 
browser client remote - 10000 rows - 6 sec 
browser client remote - 20000 rows - 18 sec 
browser client remote - 40000 rows - 40 sec
browser client remote - 75000 rows - 75 sec
```

Comment: Is the csv file also on the server?

Comment: no, the csv file is uploaded through the browser client from a remote pc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the network speed; I was put into the 10Mbps bandwidth and that caused the latency; When my network admin switched me back to 100Mbps, the data load from the remote browser client is instantaneous!

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect that the bottleneck is the time taken for the remote client to upload the 9.12mb csv file to the server running mongo.